# Crashing when using nsstring to post data

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsstring

I'm trying to send the device token and device name to my server, although it works with only the token, it crashes if i add the device name.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
    (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

NSString* systemName=[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:systemName, deviceToken];
NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", temp] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://#############/push/register.php"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

the console outputs
2013-12-31 17:41:59.294 Wellington[31788:60b] My token is: <###### ###### ###### ###### ##### ###### ######>
(lldb)

```
 NEW CODE  
 -(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

NSString* systemName=[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];

   *** NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", deviceToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSData *postData2 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", systemName] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://*********/register.php"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[request setHTTPBody:postData2];


NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

it is crashing on stared line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you do something like,

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@", systemName, deviceToken];
```

Pipe delimetered values.

**Reason your code isn't working...**:

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:systemName, deviceToken];
```

Will give you only `systemName` variables value. Because `systemName` variable string doesn't have `%@`symbol in it to the OS will not add `deviceToken` value into `temp` variable.

Comment: Now it has stopped working .. it breaks on   NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", temp] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];                says post data is equal to 0x25070000 and the other varibles are what they should be, doesnt give any other explanation

Comment: Technically you should send both value as separate POST variables. deviceToken and systemName

Comment: I'm not sure how i could do that, because they have to be in the same request so they get connected ... could you provide an example or tell me how, do i just copy the code and double it or? thanks

Comment: You can send multiple POST variables to the server in same request. Talk to your Backend API dev and you should be ok

Comment: edited code above, done that still crashing, ... i dont have a backend api dev ..? i'm using xcode